# Jquery - Using $(this) to grab the value of a text input

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, input

I am trying to set the attribute "placeholder" to all the text inputs with the value of "".

But if a value does exist for any of the inputs for ex: input value = "myValue" then I want that one input to show that value and not the placeholder.

How do I go about this with an if else statement?  Something like this?

```
if($("#colorScheme input").val("")){
$("#colorScheme input").attr("placeholder", "ex:444444");
}

else{

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`if-else` is a conditional statement and which return `true` and `false` according to conditions. In your case you assign/set value in `Input` not compare/get.

```
> $("#colorScheme input").val("") //--means you set "" value to specific input box
```

So if you want to check text inputs with the value of "", you need to use this statement like-

```
if($("#colorScheme input").val() == ""){
  $("#colorScheme input").attr("placeholder", "ex:444444");
}
else{
}
```

[Try this](http://jsfiddle.net/7dsaM/)

Answer (score 5):

You are *setting* value instead of *getting* in comparison.

*Change*

```
if($("#colorScheme input").val("")){
```

*To*

```
if($("#colorScheme input").val() == "")
```

Answer (score 2):

If you use the expression below:

```
$("#colorScheme input").val("");
```

It means that you assign value `""` to the jQuery object.

But if you use the expression:

```
$("#colorScheme input").val();
```

It means you want to get the value of this jQuery object.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for your help! It makes total sense now.  Here's what I ended up with.

```
$('.className').each( function(item) {
    if($(this).val() == ""){
    $("#colorScheme input").attr("placeholder", "ex:444444");
}
```